# Is ruby on rails designed with full page refresh in mind

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, design-patterns, crud, single-page-application

I am currently in the process of learning Ruby. I have some knowledge of Java EE.
 According to me (with my knowledge) Ruby on Rails assumes that a full page refresh (render) will be done on each request (if we dont involve backbone or remote=>true).

So the question is how do we maintain the state of the user session ? (not including cookie,or database persistance)

In Java there is a concept of backingBean which presist (till the session exist) the state of different UI section within the application.

For Eg: Let's say there is an application with different UI sections

- First section contains user info(name , age).
- Second section contains his TODO list.
- Third section contains his scratchpad.
- Forth section contains let say a input field.

Now let say user enter some text in input field and press Enter.
Now Rail create a object(oA) of a controller(A) and call a specific method of that object(oA.m).

from here the control goes to the view with controller object(oA) available to the (embedded)ruby code in the view.
Now we use this oA object to fill the dynamic data in the view.
Let say this view is render within a layout which contain the code for rendering the other 3 section of the appliation.

Now for for successfully running the code the oA object should also have the dynamic content required by the layout view.

If i am able to explain it correctly and  the above case make sense to you then below is the specific question:
Dont you think that with increasing section in application each controller has to provide data for the complete application. (Against dont repeat yourself !!)

Where as if we have the backing object corresponding to every UI section then we would only be working in controller for that specific view.

I know i am missing some pattern or might be looking thing the wrong way.
Could anybody please respond with what i am doing/thinking/using the wrong way.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/schneems/wicked for a way to do wizards (multi-step forms) in Rails.

Comment: Have you done any web development before? I don't want to be a big mean meanie, but it sounds like you'd do better to get a good introductory book rather than ask specific questions like this that may not give you the background context you actually need on how the whole system works. The first couple of chapters in most web-dev books would help you orient your thinking. Sorry if that sounds harsh, it's a reflection on your question, not you!

Comment: Thank for being polite and straight at the same time...
But i have also asked a generic question before the Example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking on page-refresh is in the realm of the browser, while the rest of your question tends more towards server-side questions. So, I try to address the server-side.

The background of the framework design from Ruby-on-Rails is: **CRUD** which improves the way to select, insert, update and delete data across a network in a database.

Across a network means that you use HTTP and the primary ways to modify data on the server-side is by processing POST and PUT requests. As soon as you want to provide more than 1 action/page you may need to work with Ajax, and you maybe leave the Rails Way. For a use case where you want to combine a Todo List, a Profile Manager, a Scratchpad, ... without a full page rrefresh, you might better go looking into client-side JavaScript frameworks (Angular, Ember, Backbone being the popular ones in the Rails community).

You also might want to do some background reading where the opinions in Ruby-on-Rails are coming from, e.g. [Why Rails is different from Java](http://www.infoworld.com/d/developer-world/rails-creator-java-and-other-junk-017), you will see that:

- 1/3 of Ruby-on-Rails is providing nice ways to deal with HTTP (= routing and controllers)
- 1/3 of Rails is providing a better interaction with a database (= ActiveRecord)
- 1/3 of Rails is better rendering/presentation of information (= ActionViews)

Comment: That was explanatory... Just to make my understanding more clear...if we constrain our-self to have full page refresh and dont use ajax then the only way out is to make hierarchy of controllers..right ?

Comment: In Rails, you typically don't use a hierarchy of controllers, but one controller that can be mapped to a resource/representation of data. In your example, you would have a ScratchpadsController, ProfilesController, TodosController; each controller can then be addressed over a route in the Routes file (= mapping an URL to a controller). You end up with modifying/showing 1 resource/page

Comment: So if we **"typically don't use a hierarchy of controllers"** then what design pattern one follow in rails to end up with modifying/showing more then 1 resource/page with full page refresh ?

Comment: Hierarchy of controllers in Rails has a different use, it is related to routes. If you have a ProfilesController for example, you can have a Admin::ProfilesController that is just for admins. It is the server-side MVC framework design, that you typically only have 1 resoure/page.

Comment: ...can you be more specific to the question in comments